# Index out of range Python query

Tags: python

I am trying to read data from a text file into a python list and then the user is supposed to choose which entry to edit which will then be overwritten back into the text file. When I read it out into the list, the list only winds up containing one item.

```
def editEntry():
f = open("address_book.txt", "r")

for line in f:
    Name, Age, Address, City = line.split(',')

    editList = []
    editList.append([Name, Age, Address, City])
    print (editList , "\n")

choice = int(input("Which entry would you like to edit?" + "\n"))
test = editList[choice]
print (test)
```

When that code is run, I can only select the index 0 when I want to select 0, 1 or 2.

Any help guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You empty editList every time before adding to it. Put editList = [] before the loop.

Comment: That has kind of worked but the output now gives this:

[['David', ' 21', ' 123 Main Street', ' Hull\n']] 

[['David', ' 21', ' 123 Main Street', ' Hull\n'], ['Jodie', ' 20', ' 124 Main Street', ' Hull\n']] 

[['David', ' 21', ' 123 Main Street', ' Hull\n'], ['Jodie', ' 20', ' 124 Main Street', ' Hull\n'], ['Emilu', ' 23', ' 125 Main Street', ' Hull']]

It repeats every option in the list every time it iterates

Comment: I can't understand that from your code. Maybe entries were duplicated in the file earlier and you need to edit them away.

Comment: All the text file contains is the three lines
David, 21, 123 Main Street, Hull
Jodie, 20, 124 Main Street, Hull
Emilu, 23, 125 Main Street, Hull

I changed the code to what you said:
`def editEntry():
    f = open("address_book.txt", "r")
    
    editList = []
    
    for line in f:
        Name, Age, Address, City = line.split(',')

        editList.append([Name, Age, Address, City])
        print (editList , "\n")

    choice = int(input("Which entry would you like to edit?" + "\n"))
    test = editList[choice]
    print (test)`

Comment: I see; you print out the whole list each time through the loop. You should either print only what you just read, or print the list after the loop.